# ER diagram for lab

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

> Draw an ER diagram for the following situation: a lab has several
> chemists who work  on one or more projects. Chemists also may use
> certain kinds of equipments on each  project.
>
> - Attributes of Chemist include EmployeeID (identifier), Name, and PhoneNo.
> - Attributes of Project include ProjectID (identifier), and StartDate.
> - Attributes of Equipment include SerialNo (identifier) and Cost.
> - The organization wishes to record AssignDate, the date when a given equipment item  was assigned to a particular chemist working on a
>   specified project.
> - The organization also wishes to record the association between the project and chemist. A chemist must be assigned to at least one
>   project. Any number of chemists may  work in a project.
> - A given equipment item need not be assigned, and a given project need not be assigned any equipment item.
>
> [image: sol]

My answer differs slightly from that answer key. I don't understand why EQUIPMENT is branched out from ASSIGNMENT. "A given equipment item need not be assigned, and a given project need not be assigned any equipment item", so why isn't EQUIPMENT branching out from PROJECT?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is easily entirely expressed in text.

Answer (score 0):

The equipment could be assigned to more than one project over its life, so this is managed in the many to many relationship within the `assignment` table

Comment: So the equipment can be linked back to assignment and traced back to proj table?

Comment: Exactly that - also means it would be easy to work out (i.e. report on) all the projects that the equipment has been historically assigned to

Answer (score 0):

erd.each employee  may be assigned to one or more  project or may not be assigned to a project,aproject must have least one employee assigned and may have any number of employee assigned.and empolyee billing rate vary from project to project and company record the BILL_RATE for each employee when assigned to particular project